# Confusion about how bucketized feature columns work

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I had some confusion about how bucketized feature columns represent input to the model. According to the [blog post on feature columns](https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/11/introducing-tensorflow-feature-columns.html), when we bucketize a feature like year this puts each value in buckets based on the defined boundaries, and creates a binary vector, turning on each bucket based on the input value, but [the example in the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/bucketized_column) shows the output as a single integer. I'm confused as to how the input is to the model when using a bucketized column. Can anyone clarify this for me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the dimensions of the first hidden layer of the estimator, it seems like for each feature column that is a `tf.feature_column.bucketized_column`, a one hot encoded vector is created based on the boundaries.